# How to query text file version of LibreOffice Thesaurus in bash (joining lines)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to write a simple script in bash to query the LibreOffice thesaurus extension as a text file. For each input query string, I want the output to be all the related strings. And I want to do this in bash.

To download and extract the thesaurus, I do

```
wget "https://extensions.libreoffice.org/assets/downloads/41/1653961771/dict-en-20220601_lo.oxt" # download LO dictionary & thesaurus

unzip -p dict-en-20220601_lo.oxt th_en_US_v2.dat > lo # extract contents of thesaurus to text file
```

Taking a look at part of the text file:

```
nine|3
(adj)|9|ix|cardinal (similar term)
(noun)|9|IX|niner|Nina from Carolina|ennead|digit (generic term)|figure (generic term)
(noun)|baseball club|ball club|club|baseball team (generic term)
nine-banded armadillo|1
(noun)|peba|Texas armadillo|Dasypus novemcinctus|armadillo (generic term)
nine-fold|1
(adj)|nonuple|ninefold|multiple (similar term)
nine-membered|1
(adj)|9-membered|membered (similar term)
nine-sided|1
(adj)|multilateral (similar term)|many-sided (similar term)
nine-spot|1
(noun)|spot (generic term)
```

So for example, I want to be able input
"nine" as a query and have bash return something like

```
9
ix
cardinal
9
IX
niner
Nina from Carolina
ennead
digit
figure
baseball club
ball club
club
baseball team
```

I think this should be fairly easy to do using the right syntax with `awk`  or `sed`, especially since all of the lines containing query terms do NOT begin with "(" and all of the line containing related terms DO begin with "(".

But I'm still somewhat of a newbie, and haven't been able to figure it out yet. The crux of the matter for me seems to be getting the query term and all related terms onto a single line. From there, I know how to `sed` my way to victory. But getting to that point has proven challenging for me.

TIA for your help!

p.s. I'm trying to do something similar to this, but my situation is a little different, and I don't understand the syntax well enough to modify it for my needs: https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/184649-sed-join-lines-do-not-match-pattern.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
v=nine
sed -n ':a;/^'"${v}"'|/{:b;n;/^[^(]/ba;s/^[^|]*|\| ([^)]*)//g;y/|/\n/;p;bb}' file
```

Focus on any lines following a match on the input variable.

Fetch the following line and if it does not begin with `(`, then repeat above.

Otherwise, remove the first field and any values between parens, replace the field separators `|` by newlines, print the result and repeat.

---

```
v=nine # set variable v to `nine`
sed -n ':a # turn off implicit printing and set goto label a
        /^'"${v}"'|/{ # match a line beginning with variable v
          :b # set goto label b
          n # fetch next line (do not print see option -n)
          /^[^(]/ba # goto label a if line does not begin (
          s/^[^|]*|\| ([^)]*)//g # remove first field and parens
          y/|/\n/ # translate | to newline for entire line
          p # print the result
          bb # goto label b
        }' file
```

To see the sed script in action invoke the `--debug` option.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Any chance you could break up the code a little bit (spaces or new lines) to help me see how each step is working? I would upvote if I had enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanations. I accepted your answer. The `--debug` option is really helpful. What exactly is a namespace in the context of this particular command?

Comment: @TaylanMorcol a namespace or label is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Branching-and-Cycles).

Comment: Thanks! This answers so many of my `sed` questions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, an Awk solution

File `search.awk`:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# This block is executed BEFORE input file treatment.
BEGIN {
    # Field Separator
    FS = "|"
}

# The next blocks are executed for each input file line only if the condition in front of the block is true

# '$1' is the first field/column. Remember, field separator in the pipe (|)
$1 == KEY {
    # Key found, flag it
    flag  = 1
    # Associated words init
    words = ""
    # Do not check the next blocks conditions, process the next line of the input file
    next
}

# If the flag is 1 and the line begins with an open parenthesis.
flag == 1 && $0 ~ /^\(/ {
    # Association found
    # For all associations (field)
    # The line treatment starts with the second field
    idx = 2
    # NF is the Number of Fields in the current line
    while (idx <= NF) {
        # get the current field word (idx in the field number, $ids it is its value)
        word = $idx
        # remove term in parenthesis
        # (in fact, replace all characters after the ' (' token by an empty string)
        gsub(/ \(.*$/, "", word)
        # save it (add it in 'words' string with a coma as separator)
        words = words "," word
        # next field
        idx += 1
    }
}

# If the flag is 1 and the line NOT begins with an open parenthesis.
#  It's the end of KEY treatment 
flag == 1 && $0 !~ /^\(/ {
    # End of association
    flag = 0
    # Print Key and words
    if (words != "") {
        print KEY words
    }
    # Reinit words
    words = ""
}

# This block is executed AFTER input file treatment.
END {
    # Special case, last word in thesaurus
    # Print Key and words
    if (words != "") {
        print KEY words
    }
}
```

Executable with:

```bash
chmod +x ./search.awk
```

Used like this:

```bash
./search.awk -v KEY="nine" lo
```

Output:

```
nine,9,ix,cardinal,9,IX,niner,Nina from Carolina,ennead,digit,figure,baseball club,ball club,club,baseball team
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! I can follow the general logic, but I don't understand awk well enough to fully understand what each step is doing (even with your thorough commenting). I would upvote this if I had enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ cat script.sed
N
{
    /\(/ {
        /9/!s/[^|]*\|//
        s/\n/ /
        {
            /[^|]*\|(9\|)/ { 
                s//\1/
                s/([^|]*)\|/\1\n/g
                s/\([^)]*\)//
                s/\([^)]*\)//g
                p
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ sed -Enf script.sed input_file
nine
9
ix
cardinal
9
IX
niner
Nina from Carolina
ennead
digit
figure
baseball club
ball club
club
baseball team
```

Comment: When I run this, I get the output (separated by newlines, but they show up as spaces instead in this comment):
`ennead
 
9
IX
niner
Nina from Carolina
digit 
figure 

9
 ardinal 
nine
9
IX
niner
Nina from Carolina
ennead
digit 
figure 
nina from carolina
 
9
IX
niner
Nina from Carolina
ennead
digit 
figure 
nine
9
ix
cardinal 
9
IX
niner
Nina from Carolina
ennead
digit 
 igure 
baseball club
ball club
club
baseball team 

9
IX
Nina from Carolina
ennead
digit 
 nineteen
2
`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the number `9`? This produces your output. You need to prevent regex characters in the query.

```
read -p 'query? ' query
[[ $query =~ [[:alnum:]_-]+ ]] &&
sed -n '
/^([^)]*)|\('"$query"'|.*\)/ {s/^([^)]*)|//; s/|/\
/g;p}' lo
```

Parsing the file properly is more complicated than this though.

Comment: This is doing something weird. When I query "nine", it returns only a partial list of results that is repeated a few times, and in some cases the output has the numeral "9" instead of the word "nine".

To clarify, I want to query the word "nine" (or whatever) in a thesaurus. I could just as well have queried any other word. It just so happens that the chunk of the thesaurus that I pulled out as an example in my original post is for the entry "nine". Perhaps that is where the confusion is coming from?

Comment: @TaylanMorcol Yeah this isn't what you want. I'm interested in this kind of stuff and started working yesterday on a thesaurus lookup CLI for the file you posted. But I can't find documentation for the data format. Roughly it looks like: `word|N` where N is the number of following lines pertaining to `word`. Prefix of each line is word type (`word` as an `adj`, `noun`, etc). Prefixes are split over multiple lines I can't work out why.

Comment: What do you mean the prefixes are split over multiple lines? BTW, the solutions proposed by potong and Arnaud Valmary both worked for me.